# Is Xcode's "delete word backward" broken or am I crazy?

Tags: xcode, keyboard, shortcut

Firstly, this type of functionality works correctly in other text editors in OSX.

In Xcode, in most cases, "delete word backward" will correctly delete the previous "word". Where it "breaks" is when the word you're deleting is the first word on a line. Xcode will delete that word and the previous word on the previous line. Illustrated below:

[image: Instead of only deleting the // on line 2, Xcode will also delete the 1 on the previous line]

Highlighted in green is the text that is deleted by one "delete word backward" command. Instead of only deleting the "//" on line 2, Xcode will also delete the "1" on the previous line

I've also tried "Delete expression backward" and "Delete subword backward" which don't make any difference.

I have the same issue with "Move word left extending selection".

I'm on OSX 10.7.5 and Xcode 4.5.2

Comment: I think this is because Xcode doesn't consider a comment delimiter to be a word. When using option-left arrow, for example, it will skip from the beginning of "This" to the left of "1", also.

Comment: It happens with any other characters as well. At the very least, you'd think it would consider a linebreak a word separator.

Comment: Any inkling of whether this gets/got fixed in 4.6? If not, is a DIY-fix even possible for this annoyance?

Comment: @courteous I've confirmed it's not fixed in 4.6.